# Can't get network access to docker container from host OS or from container to host OS

Tags: linux, docker, centos, containers, centos7

I have fresh installed docker on CentOS 7 ( XEN VPS).  I started a simple container on the server and forwarded the port:

`docker run --name mynginx2 -p 81:80 -d nginx`

I can enter containter shell and ping another container, but unfortunately I cannot reach the container from host OS:

```
curl localhost:81
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

```
ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

What I have already tried to do:

- restarting docker
- reinstalling docker
- rebooting server
- disabling ipv6 on server
- binding public ipv4 of vps or 0.0.0.0
- changing port and docker image
- killing all other linux processes
- disabling selinux, firewalld, clearing iptables rules

Some debug info from starting docker + docker container: https://pastebin.com/F5yDEtHb

Netstat:

```
netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      746/dotnet
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      432/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7070          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      433/dotnet
tcp6       0      0 :::81                   :::*                    LISTEN      11904/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      432/sshd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           443/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                443/chronyd
```

Routes:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gw-XXX-25-185.u 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d35d4c4caff1
185.25.XXX.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Interfaces:

```
br-d35d4c4caff1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:f5:d8:05:f5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4093775  bytes 1107084410 (1.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4252000  bytes 798922091 (761.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:32:23:96:40  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17  bytes 476 (476.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2095  bytes 88246 (86.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 185.25.XXX.ХХ  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 185.25.XXX.255
        ether 00:16:3e:00:80:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4093775  bytes 1107084410 (1.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4252000  bytes 798922091 (761.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1182  bytes 97010 (94.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1182  bytes 97010 (94.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethf4dec48: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 96:0c:b2:76:14:69  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

List of containers:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
c3a84f9bd9c3        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago         Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:81->80/tcp   mynginx2
```

Docker version:

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:46:54 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:45:28 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Process list:

```
root      5138  0.0  2.0 491904 38888 ?        Ssl  16:40   0:03 /usr/bin/containerd
root     11910  0.0  0.1 107692  2940 ?        Sl   18:31   0:00  \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/c3
root     11927  0.0  0.1  10620  3324 ?        Ss   18:31   0:00      \_ nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
101      11969  0.0  0.0  11016  1512 ?        S    18:31   0:00          \_ nginx: worker process
root     11735  0.0  3.4 511612 65192 ?        Ssl  18:31   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root     11904  0.0  0.1 217044  3212 ?        Sl   18:31   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 81 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container
```

Docker info:

```
docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 1.789GiB
 Name: vps-32907
 ID: 4W6H:34K5:GRRU:RZZV:JJVU:YNT6:ITN5:SSDO:PIDU:OFUY:WW73:6J5T
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Docker inspect: https://pastebin.com/gwCguw27

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Inside the container, can you `curl localhost:80`? You should see the _Welcome to nginx!_ page

Comment: Yes, it works without problem.

Comment: You said you _cleaned_ the iptables. Docker relies on iptables, to translate from the published port(:81) to the `172.17.0.2:80` listening nginx. If you don't have production containers, you can restart the docker deamon to recreate what you might have manually removed. Under iptables you should see a DNAT to the nginx container: `sudo iptables -t nat -L`  ==>> `DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:81 to:172.17.0.2:80`

Comment: I have tried with iptables rules and without, nothing changes. I can also give you SSH access to server if you need, its a test VPS.

Comment: I compared to my config and haven't spotted any unusual difference. Could be some subtle RHEL thing that's missing. Even if I ssh to the VPS, I don't have other ideas...it should just work. It's a 5 minutes setup on Ubuntu..

Comment: Yes, thats why i need help. I have another VPS with a clean Ubuntu18 and it works :(
Maybe problem in Centos settings...

Comment: Try a server reboot. Once some guys created manually DNAT rules for their containers instead of using `-p` and everything went back to normal after the reboot. Other than that...if you followed this guide https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/ it should just work. Sorry I'm not a sys-admin